# power meter gauge animation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am currently working on a power gauge in flash for a fishing game in which a user mouse inputs determine the vertical power of a gauge,there is a container rectangle MC, and a meter rectangle made of 1 height, the meter height is adjusted according to the difference calculated from the mouseStart event, and mouseMove event, is there a better way of making the calculations? because currently a slight difference will result in a big "jump" in the meter .

functions of the rod.

```
private function touchStarted(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            startY = evt.stageY;

        }
        private function rotateTurret(evt:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace("rot "+rotation);
            endY = evt.stageY;

            if (startY != 0)
            {
            difference = startY-endY  ;
            txt.text = difference.toString();
            _powerMeter.increment(difference);
            }
                 }
```

power meter function

```
private function loop(e:Event):void
    {


        fill.height += _diff;

        if (fill.height >= 200 )
            fill.height = 200;
        if (fill.height < 0)
            fill.height = 0;        

    }

    public function increment(value:Number):void
    {
        _diff = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you limit the number of pixels the user has to move the mouse to fill the power meter to the range [0..1], it's easier to separate the power meter from the actual mouse motion.

You do this by dividing the `difference` by the total length you want as the maximum number of pixels needed to completely fill the power meter.

The updated `rotateTurret` function might look like this:

```
if(startY != 0) {
    var maxPixelsNeeded:Number = 300.0;

    difference = (startY-endY) / maxPixelsNeeded;

   // -- same as before
}
```

You will also need to change the loop function, since the _diff variable will now be in the range [0..1], to:

```
fill.height = _diff * 200; // Where 200 is the max height of the power meter.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about   `_diff = value/10;`?

I can't give you better advice at the moment because I'm not entirely sure what your code does. For example: where is `loop` called?

Comment: loop is called at enterFrame for the power guage class.